# Unable to remote access MySQL - Unbuntu

Tags: mysql, remote

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04

I've bind the IP address, there are no firewalls installed, but yet connection is still being refused! I've tried everything I could find online, anyone have any way of doing this or testing to see what is actually wrong?

The "master" server is what I'm trying to connect to from a "slave" server, the master is running MySQL, and is setup with tcadmin and running fine on port 8880. What I'm struggling to do is allow remote connection from the "slave" to the "master".

Root has permission from any host.

I'm using tcadmin to connect on the master server, but when going through the setup, I get

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '151.80.108.75' (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 151.80.108.75:3306
```

in ssh this works

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1` - which works
```

but when using the IP of the server connection is refused, When connecting via the IP it gives error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '' (111)

This is all I have in the cnf file:

```
[mysql]
bind-address        = ***.***.***.***`
```

I can ping the address, it currently has tcadmin on it, which uses the port 8880 which works fine, but for some reason, I can't get the remote access to work with MySQL. I'm able to ping it from a remote location.

Doesn't allow connection via telnet, but Unsure how to open a port that isn't being blocked? There's no firewalls installed, nothing should be limiting it, port 8880 for tcadmin works fine?

Comment: stupid..........

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the port is open. From a remote host with the default port: 
`telnet <ip> 3306`

Can you show us the my.cnf file, [mysqld] section with the bind address parameter.

Can you ping that ip address at all? Do you use a hostname or an ip address to connect? If it works with ip and not hostname you may have a dns configuration issue.